# Un/availability of epsilon and varepsilon in gnuplot

Tags: labels, greek

I have been trying to get correct 'epsilon' symbol for labeling the axes in the gnuplots. From my understanding `TeX`distinguishes between two types of `epsilon` symbols: one is ε (varepsilon) and the other one is ϵ (epsilon). The latter one seems unavailable in gnuplot or I am not able to find a correct way out. And I want to use this one in my labels. 
Do I have to change to a particular font type where this is available? I tried some of the available font types but nothing worked.

I have used ϵ extensively in my document and suddenly I am a bit reluctant to use replace all in the TeX just for a single plot . Anyhow, I am also curious to know whether or not gnuplot got 'em both. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by posting a minimal compilable document (MWE).

Comment: You just have to use a font which has your required variant of epsilon.  Anyway, this question is not about TeX, so voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @HenriMenke Voting off-topic does not answer the question.

Comment: Did you read https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/discussion/5925/thread/bc8a65fe/ for a similar question about `\phi`, `\varphi`? How do you produce your epsilons at the moment? Can you add more details? Anyway, I believe Henri Menke is right. This is (very likely) not a TeX question, it's a gnuplot question and you will get better answers at a gnuplot-specific site. (The question might be on topic here if you use a gnuplot to export TeX/TikZ code.) ...

Comment: ...  This site is about TeX, and if the only link between your question and TeX is that you want to embed the plot in your TeX document that is a weak link indeed. Plus saying "Voting off-topic does not answer the question." is besides the point. If you asked a question about car mechanics on maths.stackexchange and somebody were to comment that they think the question is off topic replying with "Voting off-topic does not answer the question." is not really helping.

Comment: If you use the `{/Symbol ...}` approach you get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(typeface) and while that font has two phi variants it only has one lowercase epsilon, so I don't think you can get another one. You can try to input utf-8 directly. But you may have to tell gnuplot and all other programmes involved that you are about to use Unicode.

Comment: @moewe I agree with you about my Q being off-topic but it seems SE does not have gnuplot community. Maybe it is time to start one.

Comment: There are about 4600 questions about gnuplot on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnuplot. You could certainly ask there. There is also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot